# Angular ui-router not updating view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ui.router.title']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
 //
 // Now set up the states
$stateProvider
.state('activity', {
  title: "activity",
  url: "/activity",
  templateUrl: "/app/activity",
  resolve: {
    $title: function() { return 'Home'; }
  }
})
.state('friends', {
  title: "Friends",
  url: "/friends",
  templateUrl: "/app/friends",
  resolve: {
    $title: function() { return 'Friends'; }
  }
})

});

<a ui-sref="activity" data-ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}" ui-sref-active="active">
```

However, what happens here is that, when there's a change in the Friends' view, it doesn't reflect unless i manually have to refresh the page myself.

I've tried things like `data-ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}"` but that still doesn't get the job done.

Comment: which version of ui router you are using

Comment: @vignesh I'm using v0.2.18